# create a cascade dropdown in ASP.NET MVC 3 with C# for a given value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a property in controller like

```
public int NumberOfPersons
{
    get { return _NumberOfPersons; }
    set { _NumberOfPersons = value; }
}

private int _NumberOfNights = 7;
```

and I want to create a cascade dropdown with 7 numbers. Eg.

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
...
<option>7</option>
</select>
```

Can you please tell me how could I do?
Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View you can write this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NumberOfPersons, 
        Enumerable.Range(1,7).Select(i => new SelectListItem 
                                          { 
                                             Value = i.ToString(), 
                                             Text = i.ToString()
                                          }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example utilizing ViewData for this [SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx) constructor

```
ViewData["mylist"] = new SelectList(new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" }.Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }), "value", "text", "1");
```

In your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("myList")
```